# Backend MySQL database server

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets

I'm writing a web application where the load is distributed across multiple servers that handle requests, by doing CRUD requests on database tables on a single seperate MySQL database server. One of the requirements of my application is that we want to be able to add a new server dynamically to the network of request handling server. To do this, do I need to make the database server aware of the new server or is simply giving the new server the ip address and port number sufficient?

I'm working with java servlets at the moment and I have a properties file containing the necessary information (ip, port, username, pass, dbname) to connect to a local mysql database. Do I simply change those to point to the remote db server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a load balancing to servers. When one request is sent, the server is load balanced. Try to search for them online.